# Preview image dimensions of files in a hidden folder

Tags: macos, finder

I'm using XtraFinder as a Finder at the moment, although the problem exists with the 'default' Finder. When an image is inside a hidden folder, the image's dimensions will not show in the preview column. Is there any way to change this behaviour?

I've tried CMD+J to show View Options and activate the Show Item Info radio button, but this does nothing.

I've attached a few images to display my problem:

[image]

[image]

Note: this feature works with the PathFinder app, although I'd like to avoid using that at the moment.

Comment: It's probably because Spotlight (`mds`) doesn't index hidden folders and therefore doesn't generate metadata for the files. Checking if there's a way to have it force-index them, but it could be hard, or impossible.

Comment: @slhck I see. I thought it might be trivial as PathFinder displays the information for a hidden folder.

Comment: I haven't checked what PathFinder does (I don't have the app), but looking at similar questions (e.g. [on Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29139/force-spotlight-to-index-a-normally-un-indexed-folder)), there's really no workaround. I haven't got the "make a link to the hidden folder" thing to work for me either.